# Open TCP connection, send multiple messages and close stream later

Tags: java, tcp

How can I change this code:

```
public class bingoMachineControl {
void sendCommand(String command) throws IOException {
    String ipaddress = "192.168.0.2";
   Socket commandSocket = null;
//      PrintWriter out = null;
  BufferedWriter out = null;
  BufferedReader in = null;
  BufferedWriter outToDetailFile = null;
  FileWriter fstream = null;
  String version = "";
  int numberOfBallsInGame;
  int ledCycleState = 1;


         commandSocket = new Socket(ipaddress, 7420);

  //          out = new PrintWriter(commandSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
      out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(commandSocket.getOutputStream()));
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(commandSocket.getInputStream()));
          out.write("c");out.flush();
          out.write(command);out.flush();

                 String message = in.readLine();

     out.close();
      in.close();
      commandSocket.close();

}
}
```

To be able to connect to socket on event (let's say button click), send a message to port on event and then close the socket connection also on event.

Thank you

Comment: What is wrong with the method you have? It does all of that. Just call it in the click-Listener. Or better spawn a thread in the click-listener and have that one call it.

Comment: Every time i send command socket closes after recieveing answer. The machine i'm sending the commands to can't handle constant connects/disconnects. The machine can only accept one connection and after the connection closes machine can't accept any connections for 6 seconds after port close.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep up the connection, you'll have to make the Socket a class variable.
Then you can access it from each method in that class.

Open the socket when you instantiate the class and close when you are done with sending / receiving.

Mind that you might need to introduce a Thread for keeping the EDT clean from Network communication.